# Updating the type of the primary key column in SQL Server 2008 and Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I want to change my primary key column from `int` to `bigint`.

In SQL Server 2008, the change is done, but when I UPDATE my model from database in my project through Entity Framework, nothing happens, it doesn't see the change of the data type.

I have other tables related to this table by this primary key

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change first your models and update the database after using migrations:

1. Change your type from `int` to `bigint` in your models
2. Open `Package Manager Console` and run `Add-Migration ModifiedPKToBigInt`
3. On the same console run `Update-Database`
4. Done